# Error 1064 when inserting SQL data from a dump file into MariaDB using Python script

Tags: python, mariadb

I have written a Python script to import data from a SQL dump file into a MariaDB instance. However, when I run the script, I encounter the following error:

```
Error: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''Small Room - 2.00 Hours \r\n(08:00 PM - 10:00 PM)\r\nPeak Hours' at line 2
```

Interestingly, when I use DBeaver and connect to the database, I can successfully insert the same data without any errors using the console in DBeaver.

Here is the Python script I am using:

```
import mysql.connector

# Database connection details
host = 'localhost'
port = 3306
user = 'admin'
password = 'password'
database = 'example'

# SQL file path
sql_file = 'file_location'

try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=host,
        port=port,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        database=database
    )
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    with open(sql_file, 'r') as file:
        sql_statements = file.read()

    statements = sql_statements.split(';')

    for statement in statements:
        if statement.strip():
            cursor.execute(statement)

    connection.commit()
    print('Data imported successfully.')

except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print('Error:', error)

finally:
    if 'connection' in locals() and connection.is_connected():
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
```

Here is the SQL data I am trying to insert:

```
INSERT INTO `transactions` (`id`, `profit`, `sub_total`, `grand_total`, `gst`, `status`, `created_on`, `content`, `receive_amount`, `change_amount`, `start_time`, `end_time`, `checkout`, `outlet_id`, `staff_id`, `server_transaction_id`, `outlet_transaction_id`) VALUES
(318151, 18.69, 20.00, 20.00, 1.31, 'paid', '1480319419', 'Premium Medium Room - 3 Hours \r\n(04:00 PM - 07:00 PM)\r\nHappy Hours 3 Hours Package;19;2016-11-28 16:00:00;2016-11-28 19:00:00;132', 20.00, 0.00, '1480320000', '1480330800', b'1', 7, 1006, 318151, 36079)
```

I'm not sure why I'm encountering this error when running the script, but I can successfully execute the same SQL statement using DBeaver. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here;  please [edit] your question to retag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Comment: I suspect this: `statements = sql_statements.split(';')` might be causing the problem, if you have a text string that contains a semicolon, this code will split on that as well as the statement boundary.

Comment: The error message citates a part of problematic query. There is no this substring in your "Here is the SQL data I am trying to insert"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try printing `statements` after the line: `statements = sql_statements.split(';')`

MariaDB follows the same convention as MySQL and other SQL-based systems. In MariaDB, the semicolon (;) is used as a statement terminator to separate individual SQL commands.

When you split the loaded statements, the ";" delimiter is removed.

Try with `re`

```py
import re

# ...

# change this line
# statements = sql_statements.split(';')

# to something like this (adjust regex accordingly)
statements = re.findall(r'\b\w+(?:\s+\w+)*;', sql_statements)
```

Comment: I get the following error with re

```
Error: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'e' at line 1

```

Comment: I updated the regex pattern because I remembered you have multiple words in SQL statements, this should be more helpful.

Comment: I'm not big on regex but try to implement my suggestion and then print the statements to see how it separated the SQL statements.

Comment: Getting the same error

Comment: What does `statements` print to now vs before?

Comment: before: `'1503756000', '1503766800', b'1', 5, 1013, 525272, 43937),\n(525273, 26.17, 42.00, 28.00, 1.83, 'paid', '1503755403', 'Small Room - 3.00 Hours \\r\\n(10:00 PM - 01:00 AM)\\r\\nPeak Hours", '2', '2017-08-26 22:00:00', '2017-08-27 01:00:00', "212'`



after: `00;', 'nHappy Hours;', '1;', '00;', '00;', 'nHappy Hours;', '5;', '00;', '00;', 'nHappy Hours;'`

Comment: Okay, so we are getting somewhere. Can you please update your question to include the link to actual file you're trying to read with `sql_statements = file.read()`, because it seems to differ from what you just pasted?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Phillips suggestion above I managed to workout the issue and update the code to do the following

```py
    with open(sql_file, 'r') as file:
        sql_statements = file.read()

    # Split the SQL statements
    statements = re.split(r';\s*\n', sql_statements)

    # Remove the last empty statement after the last semicolon
    statements = statements[:-1]
```

The regular expression r';\s*\n' is used to split the string. This pattern matches a semicolon followed by optional whitespace characters and a newline character. This pattern assumes that each SQL statement in the file ends with a semicolon followed by optional whitespace and a newline.

It removes the last empty statement after the last semicolon from the statements list. This is done by slicing the list using statements[:-1], which creates a new list containing all elements except the last one. This is necessary because the last statement in the list would be empty since it follows the last semicolon in the file